# In FireFox the "Location.prototype" doesn't "really" inherit from "Object.prototype"?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, location

I test Location object and have some doubts;  Location.prototype doesn't really inherits "Object" 's property; for example

```
Object.prototype.testProperty = 5;
```

Then if we retrieve "location.testProperty"  we just get "undefined";  Theoretically location is the instance of "Location",  and Location.prototype chains to Object, so it is expected to inherit all Object.prototype's properties;  but in FF this rule is broken.  I don't know why ? Do someone know the reason ?   By the way,  such testing hasn't problem in IE / Chrome

Comment: I cannot even access `location.constructor.prototype` without getting an error in firefox

Comment: The Location object is a host object (similar to DOM objects), and therefore not subject to normal ECMAScript rules.

Comment: So different browser may have its own implementation for the host object? As I said in IE/Chrome the location seems "normal"